# how to get clone element of queryselectorall and append to another div

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get clone elements of more than one specific classes list and append to another tag.

```
var elements = document.getElementById('main_iframe').contentDocument.querySelectorAll(".optdel, .optbold");
var editsummary = document.getElementById("opteditsum");

    for (var i=0, im=elements.length; im>i; i++) {                        
      editsummary.appendChild(elements[i]);          
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming there are no [same originl policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) constrains, you can [clone the node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode)

```
var elements = document.getElementById('main_iframe').contentDocument.querySelectorAll(".optdel, .optbold");
var editsummary = document.getElementById("opteditsum");

for (var i = 0, im = elements.length; im > i; i++) {
    editsummary.appendChild(elements[i].cloneNode(true));
}
```

Comment: If any possiblity to goto link between clone element to document element. i.e. When in click the clone element on dialouge box. need to go on iframe content