# Appending a DIV from the contents of body removes the DOM elements

Tags: javascript, dom, append

Following is my code

```
;(function(window){

    var description_window= document.querySelector('.post_description');

    var $headings= document.querySelectorAll('.blog_main_content h3');

    for (var i = $headings.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        description_window.appendChild($headings[i]);
    };

})(window);
```

Here ".post_description" is the class of the DIV to which I am attempting to append the elements. The elements are the H3 elements of the '.blog_main_content'. However, doing this removes the h3 elements from the blog main content.

Could someone assist

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clone the node in question, currently `$headings` refers to the actual DOM content, not a js version of it. You can use [cloneNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) to do so. Something like:

```
;(function(window){

var description_window= document.querySelector('.post_description');

var $headings= document.querySelectorAll('.blog_main_content h3');

for (var i = $headings.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

    description_window.appendChild($headings[i].cloneNode(true));
};
```

})(window);

A similar question was asked here as well [how to get clone element of queryselectorall and append to anothor div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30136508/how-to-get-clone-element-of-queryselectorall-and-append-to-anothor-div)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That worked. I have an additional query. What if I need to change the collected h3 elements to a tag in the target div.

Comment: There isn't a way to alter a tag like that. You could copy the text content of the h3 node into a newly created node in your loop. You could use the `document.createElement('your-tag')` function after pulling the `textContent` from each h3.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to Clone thé elements with the cloneNode(true) command. This creates a deep copy. If you don't need deep copy, use cloneNode(false)